# How to continuously sending data to the port(TCP) by using java?

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to send continuously data to the client whether the client is using the data or not.
I tried in below manner :

```
public class Ser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number,temp;
    try {
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
        Socket clientSocket = s1.accept();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        number = 0;
        while (number <= 100) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("here");
            out.println(number);
            number++;
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

But above code is not working. 
How can I send continuously data to port in windows?

Comment: Please indicate what makes you think it's not working. What is the client code?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to continuously send data to a client over a `Socket` if the client is not going to consume (read) the data.  (

- When I say "not possible" ... if a server could send indefinitely without block, then the "pipe" would need to be able to buffer an indefinitely large amount of data.  That would be impractical to implement.
- And there would be huge problems implementing something whereby a client could skip over data without reading it.  How would it know when to stop skipping?

You could use datagrams (e.g. UDP) and a `DatagramSocket` but then you have the reverse problem.  The client *may not be able to* receive all of the data sent.

---

I note that there was an error in the original version of your question, but I am assuming that it was a simple typo and not present in your actual code.

Comment: Thank's for u r reply, for client only need latest data he don't want's previous data.Like RFID reader sending continuously data to port.(like that manner i want)

Comment: That doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @paper1111 -- Please explain that in your own answer.  Note that what we are looking is at server-side code that is sending data, not the client side that is reading the data.  The requirement is that the sender can send irrespective of what the client does.

Comment: And the fact remains that even with a correction, the program cannot do what the OP is actually asking to do.